# google_organization_iam_custom_role with yaml file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

How can I create a custom role reading the list from a yaml file? Any example would be helpful.

In the below example I want to read permissions from a yaml file.

```
resource "google_project_iam_custom_role" "my-custom-role" {
  role_id     = "myCustomRole"
  org_id      = "123456789"
  title       = "My Custom Role"
  description = "A description"
  permissions = ["iam.roles.list", "iam.roles.create", "iam.roles.delete"]
}
```

yaml file has list of permissions

```
role_id: myCustomRole
title: title of myCustomRole
description: description for myCustomRole
permissions:
- iam.roles.list
- iam.roles.create
- iam.roles.delete
```

please also suggest if I can format it in a better way.

Comment: What does the input YAML file look like?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR - have updated question with yaml file

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a job for [the `file` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/file.html). Also you need to convert type from a string to a list of strings (I use `split` for that).

I haven't tested it, but try this:

```
permissions = split(",", file("${path.module}/permissions.list"))
```

Comment: I am going to try this.

Comment: For the current version of the question the answer is wrong. There's nothing parsing the YAML file format here.

Comment: I figured answer is reading a comma delimited and creating a list. For the yaml file I only added yamldecode.
permissions = yamldecode(file("${path.module}/permissions.yaml")).permissions

file function is what I was missing. I still do not know how can I give file path outside the path.module, so it can run from any location (including when move to prod or any other environment)?

Comment: Doesn't `file()` accept a relative path outside of `path.module` or absolute path (which would not be a good idea for other reasons).
You need to think what other users of your Terraform code will face. Will they have the same file system structure? Will they have the same files outside of your Terraform module?